# Changing values of object in main

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a problem with modifying object's values from my main method.

```
class player
{
public:

int a=1;
};
```

How can i work with *int a* when im not in the object,
for example i want to add 10.
when i want to print out a+10 to a console it works

```
player *test = new player()
//this works , result is 11
cout << test->a + 10 << endl;
//but when i try to do :
(test->a-10); //it compiles but the value doesnt change
```

i tried to do access the value in few ways but nothing works eg.

```
*(test->a)-10;
(*test->a -10) ;
```

how can i work with this value directly ? 
i thought of turning a into *a but or a shared_ptr but i need to know if there is a way to change it directly .

This is my first post, I searched through stack overflow and couldn't find anything relating to my problem.

Thanks

Comment: `test->a = test->a -10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should read up an intro C++ book. Regarding the question, `test->a -= 10` should work. It is equivalent to `test->a = test->a - 10`. Here, `test->a` is equivalent to `*(test.a)`.

Answer (score 0):

`(test->a-10);` would not change the value; neither does `cout << test->a + 10 << endl;` but you can see the mutated value when printing it. It doesn't actually change the value though.

You need to do something like `test->a -= 10;` to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `test->a+10`, you do not change the value of `test->a`. You only print a value that is `10` greater than what is in `test->a`.

The right way to do so is `test->a += 10` or `test->a = test->a + 10`.